# How to manage languages in my Joomla 2.5 component?

Tags: joomla, multilingual, joomla2.5

I'm writing a gallery component for Joomla 2.5 where an image has three properties, similar to categories, that should be displayed in a selected language. Current goal is to support three languages.

Imagine hundreds of vehicle images. Each image is assigned a Type ("van" or "truck" or a "bus"), a Color Name ("aquamarine", "deep jungle green") and, say, a Team Name — all of these list items have translations, and are selected from a limited number of items.

So my choices are:

1. use Joomla Categories, i.e. create three categories sets `com_my.type`, `com_my.color`, `com_my.team` and add each in three languages;
2. manage languages inside component: add extra tables with `[id, language, text]` fields.

In your experience, which one would be smart and convenient to manage?

Comment: I'm not clear on why you wouldn't use Joomla!'s mutli-language support?

Comment: @cppl I got used to developing for 1.5 and still uncomfortable with 2.5 internals. I.e. its not obvious for me, how to tie three different categories, in each respective language, to a single image item in my component.

Also I doubt that its convenient for users to add each language version of a single category one by one using component forward to native Joomla Category creation page, instead of filling three neighbor fields - same content, three languages, not bothering with all the extra fields that Joomla offers in that dialog.

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing shouldn't be complicated. Simply use the `JText::_('TEXT_INPUT_HERE')` and translate it in each language file. Storing the languages in the database isn't very user friendly as there are a lot people who translate extensions into the language of their choice as it not supported by default. Translating extensions using Joomla's multi-language support is the same with J1.5 as it is with J2.5

Comment: Strings to be translated are not that static. Imagine hundreds of vehicle images, each having description, vendor description and type title (i.e. "van", "bus") — translated. Its a task for content manager person to enter/edit these via admin interface, rather than prepare static language files.

Comment: well yes if you are referring to content such as description that users themselves write, then this can't be static, however you can either translate them manually or have it done automatically done with something like google translate.

Comment: Translation will be done manually. Trying to figure out if the native Joomla Categories are suitable for this kind of task here.